# I meet an surprised error in Google tensorflow2.0 tutorials in text_classification_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

When i reading Google tensorflow2.0 tutorials, i meet an surprised error when i try to test in my jupyter. It is so strange！It run fluently in Google colab! The tutorials is [this](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn?hl=en) 
My computer GPU is gtx1060 6G, and memory is 16G, I think my computer is ok to run this tutorials.

I try run it on Jupyter, and it run error.But run fluently on Google colab!

You can see the error code following or [go to the web](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn?hl=en):

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
# tfds.disable_progress_bar()
(train_data, test_data), info = tfds.load(
    'imdb_reviews/subwords8k', 
    split = (tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST), 
    with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
encoder = info.features['text'].encoder
padded_shapes = ([None],())
train_batches = train_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10, padded_shapes = padded_shapes)
test_batches = test_data.shuffle(1000).padded_batch(10, padded_shapes = padded_shapes)

embedding_dim=16

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Embedding(encoder.vocab_size, embedding_dim,mask_zero=True),
    layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_batches,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=test_batches, validation_steps=20,verbose=2)
```

It is my first time meeting this error, and I don't know how to fix it, but it run fluently on Google colab, I don't know why?
The error following:

```py
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8f27353fef79> in <module>
     31     train_batches,
     32     epochs=10,
---> 33     validation_data=test_batches, validation_steps=20,verbose=2)

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    485       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    486       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 487       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    488     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    489       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 1823     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1824 
   1825   @property

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1139          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1140                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1141         self.captured_inputs)
   1142 
   1143   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1222     if executing_eagerly:
   1223       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
-> 1224           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1225     else:
   1226       gradient_name = self._delayed_rewrite_functions.register()

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    509               inputs=args,
    510               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 511               ctx=ctx)
    512         else:
    513           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

c:\users\sha\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

CancelledError:  [_Derived_]RecvAsync is cancelled.
     [[{{node Reshape_11/_38}}]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_16087]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Thanks for anyone help me！

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the batch_size, it should work.

Comment: No, it isn't the batch_size. It will run fluently on Google colab, but will run error on jupyter and my pycharm. My GPU is GTX 1060 6G and memory is 16G.

Comment: You can choose GPU on google-colab? Isn`t it defalut cpu or gpu? No version can choose?

Comment: Did you try on you own envrionment such as jupyter or pycharm? You just run on google-colab?

Comment: I was trying to see what GPU it runs on Colab. The reason for this is that if it runs on 16GB and you run the exact same code on 6GB, it may be a memory issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don`t know what GPU I choose, you can try, it just a choice.